# Overriding Backbone.Collection.prototype.add

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to override the collection.add method globally in backbone like so:

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype._add = Backbone.Collection.prototype.add;
Backbone.Collection.prototype.add = function(models, options) {
    var = newModels = models.items;
    Backbone.Collection.prototype._add(newModels, options);
}
```

The api I'm using ALWAYS contains the actual models one level down for collections. Under `items` and I find myself overriding the `.add` method for all collections. I tried what I have above but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: Note: `var = newModels = models.items;` should be `var newModels = models.items;`. I'm aware of it but that is not what is breaking the code.

Comment: Ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
var Example = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    add: function(models, options) {
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, models.items, options);
    }
})
```

Then you can extend all collections from `Example`.

Comment: Thanks. That is basically what I am doing per collection right now. At this point going back and changing all my collection definitions would be too much work. My hope was to find something that would apply globally so then rather than deviating from the norm I'd be removing code. Thanks!